# Как удалить файл из Pull Request?

Tags: git

Можно ли удалить файл с пулл реквест?
без удаления его на проекте, удаляем только с пулл реквест

Answer (score 1):

Находясь в своем бранче

```
git revert last_common_commit..HEAD -- path/to/file
git push origin HEAD
```

Либо

```
git checkout last_common_commit -- path/to/file
git add path/to/file
git commit
git push origin HEAD
```

Где last_common_commit - это коммит от которого сделан бранч.

Зы. По сути это, конечно, не удаление, а просто еще один коммит, возвращающий файл к исходному состоянию, но в ПР его будет не видно.

Comment: спасибо! попробую